# General Q: how does XAMPP and MySQL databases work together?

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I know vague, general-ish questions should be avoided, but any enlightenment on the subject matter would be much appreciated.

I have successfully created a database by using PHPMyAdmin in the XAMPP package to create a user and then having a PHP file in htdocs connect to it:

```
<?php 
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "admin";
$password = "potato";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

As the old programming joke goes, though, now that it works, *why*. I do not understand how simply putting `$servername = "localhost";` is connecting this PHP file way down in htdocs to the database file out in the xampp directory.

The reason I want to know is so I can move the database folder into the same directory as my PHP (htdocs/Projects/P8/...) so that I can upload new data and such to GitHUB easily and work on the same files and data at another workstation, as well as download SSMS and use that. I am not sure how to do this, as I cannot figure out how it's connecting even now, much less how to modify that connection to point somewhere else.

Comment: Mysql is not a file based database like ms access. You connect to a mysql server instance named pipe or sockets. Mysql stores data in its own data folder, which does not have to be in the php folder. Mysql manages the file gor you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MYSQL stores it data in a separate location and in a specific binary structure. Generally, you don't commit your SQL servers data directory to a git repository.

A better way to move data between systems is by making a dump of your database, using the [mysqldump tool](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump-sql-format.html) (included with mysql).

You can then load that file on a different system, and have exactly the same data structure & data.

You could also commit this in a git repository, but that's usually not a good idea as the file would be very hard to diff due to it's huge size and machine generated format.